# How to pass request parameter with post method from a controller to another controller method in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, controller

I want to call the method of `B` controller from `A`controller.So I used this method

`return redirect()->action('UserController@subscribe()');`

But here I am facing an issue here. I want to pass below param as in request body to above `subscribe()`

```
 $package_id = session('package_id');
 $package_type = session('package_type');
```

Please help me out how can I pass above param in request in laravel

Comment: this works for `get` methods only. you can pass those variables as parameter not as `Request` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to call one controller from another, it seems like you have not so good architecture, and you have to refactor your code.

But, if you anyway want to do it, you can do it like that:

```php
app('App\Http\Controllers\UserController')->subscribe($package_id, $package_type);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can append them to the query string.

```
return redirect()->action('UserController@subscribe', [
    'package_id' => $package_id,
    'package_type' => $package_type,
]);
```

You can call the controller.

```
app(UserController::class)->subscribe();
```

Comment: You can not POST a redirect.

Answer (score 1):

**Controller 1**

```
public function method1()
{
    $package_id = session('package_id');
    $package_type = session('package_type');
    return app('App\Http\Controllers\Controller2')->method2($package_id, $package_type);
}
```

**Controller 2**

```
public function method2($package_id, $package_type)
{
    //
}
```